# type 'string' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' in flutter firebase database

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

When i run this code i get an error:
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index', and the app doesn’t run. Can someone please tell me where is the problem or why it is getting this error?
I am trying here to retrieve data from the firebase realtime database.

```
void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
    
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
      runApp(NGU_APP());
    }
    
    // ignore: camel_case_types
    class NGU_APP extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: MyHomepage(),
          routes: {
            "login": (_) => LoginScreen(),
            "signup": (_) => RegistrationScreen(),
          },
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyHomepage extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyHomepage({key}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      _MyHomepageState createState() => _MyHomepageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomepageState extends State<MyHomepage> {
     @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        // getmessages();
        dbref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF6D0131),
            body: SafeArea(
                child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              query: dbref,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                  Animation animation, int index) {
                // var x = snapshot.value['Login'];
                // print(x);
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(snapshot.value['Main Page']),
                );
              },
            )),
          ),
        );
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Snapshot is a JSON array. Try to use:

```
snapshot.value[index]['Main Page']
```

Instead of:

```
snapshot.value['Main Page']
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn’t work.

Comment: so, try this please snapshot.value.toString()

Comment: Also, try to check the snapshot   snapshot.value.forEach((k,v) {
        print(k); print(v);
     });

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't work too.

Comment: Could you please provide the result of printing your snapshot?